# Is there any reason why toBeInViewport() shouldn't replace toBeVisible() in most circumstances?

Tags: playwright, playwright-typescript

I have been using `.toBeVisible()` to check if an element is displayed on the page. However in a few circumstances the element is visible to human eye and intractable. In these cases I've been using `toBeInViewport()`.

Would there be a downside to replacing all instances of `toBeVisible()` with `toBeInViewport()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simplistic way to show a fundamental difference between those two is by running this test:

```js
import { expect, test } from "@playwright/test";

test("Test 1", async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto("https://playwright.dev/docs/actionability");
 
  // A locator further down on the webpage:
  const locatorToFind = page.getByText("Element is considered receiving pointer events");

  await expect.soft(locatorToFind).toBeInViewport(); 
  // Fails as you need to scroll down to see the text
  
  await expect.soft(locatorToFind).toBeVisible(); 
  // Passes as the locator is visible on the page if you scroll
});
```

Which, as pointed out in an earlier answer, results in `toBeInViewport()` risks being more flaky.

Answer (score 1):

I have the feeling that using `toBeInViewport` would make your assertions more strict and eventually more flaky.